# Why does my select option function via index, not .val, not work?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

Why I get always "sort area" as feedback, at both selections? What is my fail?

```js
$('select[name="sorting"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).index = 0){
        alert("sort country");
    }
    else if ($(this).index = 1){
        alert("sort area");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="sorting">
      <option value="" class="country" selected>Country</option>
      <option value="" class="area">Area</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It shows effort and an explanation of the goal. Sure there's some issues, but that's the point of all the questions here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thx dude, I absolutly agree!

Comment: Any amount of basic debugging should have revealed both problems - maybe not their solutions, but at least it would point you in the right direction. When I encounter a problem like this, I log my values to see what's actually happening, instead of [posting a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your code. First `=` is used to *set* a value. To *compare* values you need to use `==` or `===`, depending on how you want/need to coerce data types.

Secondly you're looking at the index of the `select` element in the DOM, not the index of the `option` which was selected. As such you need to use `find()` within the event handler to get the selected `option` and retrieve its `index()`. Try this:

```js
$('select[name="sorting"]').change(function() {
  var idx = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
  if (idx === 0) {
    console.log("sort country");
  } else if (idx === 1) {
    console.log("sort area");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sorting">
  <option value="" class="country" selected>Country</option>
  <option value="" class="area">Area</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In fact, I think it's much safer just getting the `value` of the select element, instead of trying to sniff out the index of the selection option.